# how to make a slideshow full width images

Tags: wordpress, gallery, carousel, image-gallery

NOTE: This site is on wordpress.com (no plugins, and very much a restricted version of wordpress).

I would like to create a slideshow with full width images.

I was reading up on options here (but I'm still confused):
http://en.support.wordpress.com/images/gallery/#gallery-shortcode

I'm using the gallery shortcode with type=slideshow.

I've tried using size=full but it doesn't seem to affect the image width (the image seems to come through as ?w=462)

Can I alter the image width in a nice way with wordpress or do I need to revert to CSS hacks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the page template I was using ("Front Page") wasn't using the full width of the page. It worked fine with the "Full Page Width".

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using css on the slideshow image:

```
.slideshow-slide img{
min-width:100%;
height:auto;    
}
```

Check if the image is wrapped in a div also; this may restrict the image width